# Container of template classes without template parameter

Tags: c++, class, c++11, polymorphism, containers

I'm wondering if you can have a container with objects with varying template parameters.

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

template <class T>
class base
{
    public:
        T val;
        base(T newVal): val(newVal) {}; 
};

class derived : public base<int>
{
    public:
        derived(int newVal): base(newVal) {}; 
};

int main ( void )
{
    std::list < base<?> > base_collection;
    return 0;
}
```

I want my current project to be as flexible and dynamic as possible, with little extra coding when a new derived class is necessary, and my current implementation makes it important that such a list exists.

Is there a commonly used, benefiting and clean way of achieving exactly this?

Comment: "my current implementation makes it important that such a [heterogeneous] list exists". Oh. That's an anti-pattern. You need to ditch that design.

Comment: No you can't. `base<int>` is a *completely different type* to `base<float>`. And you can't store a derived class object in a base class variable anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible implementation would be using the *double dispatching*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

struct visitor;

struct dispatchable {
    virtual void accept(visitor &v) = 0;
};

template <class>
struct base;

struct visitor {
    template<typename T>
    void visit(base<T> &);
};

template <class T>
struct base: dispatchable {
    T val;
    base(T newVal): val(newVal) {};
    void accept(visitor &v) override { v.visit(*this); }
};

struct derivedInt : base<int> {
    derivedInt(int newVal): base(newVal) {}; 
};

struct derivedDouble : base<double> {
    derivedDouble(double newVal): base(newVal) {}; 
};

template<>
void visitor::visit(base<int> &) {
    std::cout << "int" << std::endl;
}

template<>
void visitor::visit(base<double> &) {
    std::cout << "double" << std::endl;
}

int main ( void ) {
    visitor v{};
    std::list <dispatchable*> coll;
    coll.push_back(new derivedInt{42});
    coll.push_back(new derivedDouble{.42});
    for(auto d: coll) d->accept(v);
}
```

This way, you have only to define the specialized function that deals with the new `base<T>` type you want to introduce.
As an example, if you want to use `base<char>`, you have to define:

```
template<>
void visitor::visit(base<char> &) {
    std::cout << "char" << std::endl;
}
```

Note that I supposed you want to treat each specialization of `base<T>` in a different way.   Otherwise, it's enough to define the generic member function `visitor::visit` and drop the specializations.

---

Side note: do not use naked pointers.
This is an example. In production code, I'd use smart pointers instead.

Comment: This is acceptable as long as there's only one relevant operation per class, such as `process event`.

Comment: @JohanLundberg OP wants to process `base<T>` for each `T`, nothing more. As he mentioned in a comment to your answer, he *wants* to use `val`. This way he can use it. Double dispatching fits well in this case. What's exactly the problem?

Comment: @skypjack, The 'problem' if you would call it that is the burden when you would like to do other things in addition to cout for each type. Your answer is fine.

Answer (score 3):

It's not completely clear why you need to do this, or what operations you intend to perform on the elements of the list (btw, consider using std vector instead). I suggest you make a common non-templated base class that base inherits from:

```
struct mainbase {
  virtual ~mainbase() = default;
};

template <class T>
class base : public mainbase
{
    public:
        T val;
        base(T newVal): val(newVal) {}; 
};


class derived : public base<int>
{
    public:
        derived(int newVal): base(newVal) {}; 
};

int main ( void )
{
    std::list < std::unique_ptr<mainbase>> > base_collection;
    return 0;
}
```

After all, if you're going to put them all in a vector, you most likely require a common set of operations which you can perform with those objects. Put those in `mainbase`.

As @BenjaminLindley points out, you can't have polymorphism by-value. That's why you would use a pointer [(such as unique_ptr)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr): `std::unique_ptr<mainbase>`.

With C++17 there's a proposal (on track) for [std::any](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any), which could be used instead, but you would still have to perform a specific cast to get the content with the correct type.

Comment: How would you access val from the mainbase object without casting?

Comment: @reign, you really can't.

Comment: @JohanLundberg: If you're just storing mainbase objects, you can't possibly have polymorphic behavior. You have no way to make use of the derived class functionality.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, Thank you - right, just copied the original code. list< pointer >. I'll update.

Comment: And if that base_collection was holding pointers, is it then possible to access val?

Comment: @reign: What do you plan to do with val? How can you even know what operations are possible if val can be any type?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I was originally using templated callback functions to handle val.